# No warning for hiding non-virtual methods with similar prototype (G++ 4.4)

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

In our projects it happens (rarely but it happens) that in a derived class a non-virtual method from the base-class is hidden by a method with the same prototype. In that case the compiler (in our case g++ 4.4) stays quiet. While I can see that no warning can be useful for private methods, for protected or public methods this should be at least a configurable warning.

If such a things exists I'm unable to find it.

Here's a small example I'd like to have g++ complain about (be assured that this kind of code-pattern is never written like this in one shot, usually work was at some point in time a virtual method in A and was inexplicably changed later):

```
class A
{
public:
    void work(int p)
    { /* do something */ }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void work(int p) 
    { /* do something different */ }
};
```

Result: no warning even with -Wall -Wextra.

Comment: From the compilers point of view, there is nothing suspect about your example, therefore no warning. However, I agree that it might have been good to find these overloads, so a flags for some kind of informational message might have been nice.

Comment: GCC 4.7 will finally implement the new C++11 `final`/`override` keywords that should help...

Answer (score 1):

You're not overriding the method, you're hiding it. It's a C++ feature.

You can take a look at [this link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9).

Also, an interesting extract:

> Note: warnings are not part of the standard, so your compiler may or
>   may not give the above warning.

Comment: Is this really overloading? I thought `A::work()` and `B::work()` are in different scopes.

Comment: @KerrekSB right. I was going through that article again and realized I was wrong.