# Warning on hiding base functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, method-hiding

I have a C++ code base where some non-virtual methods in a base class or overriden/hidden by virtual or non-virtual methods in derived classes. Mostly this is an error in the code.

Is there anything I can do to automaticly check for such cases like a compiler warning or a tool?

This is similar to [Prevent derived classes from hiding non virtual functions from base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997210/prevent-derived-classes-from-hiding-non-virtual-functions-from-base) or [No warning for hiding non-virtual methods with similar prototype (G++ 4.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213847/no-warning-for-hiding-non-virtual-methods-with-similar-prototype-g-4-4) but I'm looking for an actual solution to detect these issues in an existing codebase. Maybe just a warning for hidden functions is enough (I think that list will be small enough to go through one by one)

Changing the code base by hand to add "override" or "final" or so is not an option as this check should only be done once. A global solution like a define to "final" all non-virtual functions preventing them from beeing hidden would be ok.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 but also have access to ubuntu and gcc.

Comment: "Changing the code base by hand to add "override" or "final" or so is not an option as this check should only be done once." Can you not take your functions that you want to check, make them virtual if they aren't virtual currently, and add a `final` specifier to them and compile it just to see where it get overridden and then change it back after you're done?

Comment: @RyanP Sounds like a big codebase, and OP not wanting to do it by hand.

Comment: Isn't `/W4` enough? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay4h0tc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ RyanP yep. Big codebase and I want to check ALL of them... @dyp W4 outputs way to much and I haven't found a warning for that particular case (if there is I can manually enable it which would be great)

Comment: I have linked C4263 above, which specifically is about functions hiding, but not overriding, functions of base classes.

Comment: @dyp Although this warning is useful, it is not what I need. My base class' method is non-virtual but C4263 warns for hiding virtual functions only and even not that but only for hiding by different signature. I need a warning for a missing virtual in the base class.

Comment: @Flamefire Well if the base class function is virtual, and the derived class function has the same name and signature, it is overriding the base class function. This is usually not an error. But I agree, this is probably not what you're looking for. I couldn't find any warnings in gcc nor msvc that specifically addressed this kind of name hiding. IIRC, PCLint can diagnose that; you could also try writing your own checker for the clang static analyser.